# Ignore trailing slash from RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

I have a URL blah.com/a/

And I have a file cached/a.html

How can I tell my htaccess to ignore the trailing slash in order to look for and show a.html instead of a/.html

Note: removing the slash from the URL is not an option as the URL patterns are already set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because %{REQUEST_URI} is adding the trailing slash to the target which maps to an invalid uri /file/.html , to solve this you need to use a backrefrence instead.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /cached/$1.html [L]
```